# I want to have equal height div in react js . Is it suitable to use jquery Equal height plugin?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I want to have equal height elements in react js . Is it suitable to use jquery Equal height plugin? And how can i get its npm dependeny.

I have taken reference from this link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-equal-height

Comment: Are you looking for [How to make equal height columns](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp) or [this codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ajeets/pen/LYbmdrG)?

Comment: I want to use jqueryEqualHeight plugin in my react js project. I am not sure where can I get the npm dependency. I have also added a link which I am using as a reference.

Comment: "I am not sure where can I get the npm dependency": What does it mean? Does it mean that you don't know how to "install" this in your React project? You can run this command: `npm i jquery-equal-height`

Comment: See https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally

Comment: It is not good to mix jquery and React in a project. What you are trying to do can simply be done using CSS. And it seems like `jquery Equal height` plugin is not being maintained. So, go for CSS, better use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap